# Difference between 2 dates throws java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: jsp, date

I  am new to JSP and I need help for calculating difference between 2 dates in seconds, which gets the date input from a form in the "yyyy-MM-dd" format. But while I compile it I get the error.
Please help me in correcting it.

## Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1380)
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:355)
    at org.apache.jsp.datediff2_jsp._jspService(datediff2_jsp.java:105)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

## My code is as follows:

```
<%@ page language ="java" import="java.sql.*,java.text.SimpleDateFormat, java.util.Date,java.text.*, java.util.Calendar" %>
<html>
<body bgcolor="pink">
<form method="post">
<input  name="T1" value="2013-07-01"/> 
<input  name="T2" value="2013-07-31"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="B1">
</form>

<%

String dStart = request.getParameter("T1");
String dStop = request.getParameter("T2");

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

Date d1 = null;
Date d2 = null;

try {
d1 = format.parse(dStart);
d2 = format.parse(dStop);

out.print(d1);

long difference = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();

long seconds = difference / 1000;

out.print(seconds);

} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
%>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works fine. Do you have any other relevant code, that you are not showing? BTW, you should not do these kinds of stuffs in JSP.

Comment: Are you sure that `T1` and `T2` are set?

Comment: T1 and T2 are null initially till the user hits the submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, this is a self-submitting form, the first time the page loads `T1` and `T2` would not be set. So, use an `if` block to check for `null`s and skip the date arithmetic if parameters are not set. JSP would load fine then.

```
<%
  String dStart = request.getParameter("T1");
  String dStop = request.getParameter("T2");

  if (dStart != null && dStop != null) {
    // rest of the code
  }
%>
```

Once you submit the dates, your date arithmetic code would get executed as well.